# How many socks would you have to draw from the dark room in the worst case, to have exactly $N$ pairs?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are $A$ red socks, $B$ green socks and $C$ yellow socks in a dark room. $N$ pairs of matching colored socks from the dark room have to be drawn. Given all $A,\ B$, and $C$ are even and $N \leq \frac{1}{2}(A+B+C)$, how many socks would you have to draw from the dark room in the worst case, to have exactly $N$ pairs?

Comment: how many socks do you need to get one pair?

Comment: Note that in order to get  $N$ pairs at least $2N$ socks are needed.  How many socks could you pick (even in a well-lighted room) without getting $N$ pairs?

Comment: To have "exactly $N$" or "at least $N$"? If "exactly" what does "in the worst case" mean?

Comment: No. of socks in the worst case
Let A=2, B=4,C=4
If N=1
No. Of socks picked = 4 
1 red 1 green 1 yellow.
In the next draw no matter what you take out ,it would pair up.

N=3,
Ans= 7
Can be observed.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @rishabhkumar In your example with $A=2$, $B=4$, $C=4$, $N=1$, picking $4$ socks does not work. You might get $2$ red socks and $2$ green socks, and then you would have $2$ pairs, but the requirement is ***EXACTLY*** $1$ pair. (If that's not what you meant, then I can't imagine what you did mean by "exactly" $N$ pairs.)

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider a set I1 and an application f1:I1 -->{R,G,Y}. In order to be sure of getting a #f^{-1}(x)=2 for x in {R,G,Y}, at least #I1=#{R,G,Y}+1=4.
At least there exists two elements  i and j of I1 such that f1(i)!=f1(j). Let's consider the set NC(I1) that contains the elements of I1 which do not form a couple.
Let's consider the set I2 such that the application f2:CN(I1)+I2 -->{R,G,Y} satisfies the same properties as f1, in that case at least #[CN(I1)+I2]=4 so #I2=2. And so on, at least we need to draw 4 +2(N-1)=2(N+1) from the dark room to be sure of getting N pairs of socks. In this case we must need A+B+C>=2(N+1).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

To generalize the result with p different colour of socks in the dark room we need to draw $p+1+2(N-1) at least from the dark house in order to be sure of getti g N pairsof socks.